# GitHub Codespaces 502 Gateway Error Serving a docfx site

Tags: docker, github, docfx, codespaces

I am working to add GitHub Codespaces to the NUnit docs repository for document editing. We're really excited about the potential of Codespaces for our use case!

### The Current Ingredients

- PR to add codespaces, which has our configuration files and containers: https://github.com/nunit/docs/pull/563
- The source of the Dockerfile we're referencing from our Codespaces Dockerfile: https://github.com/nunit/docfx-action/blob/master/Dockerfile

### Reproduction

- Open the codespace
- Open the terminal
- `cd docs`
- `docfx build` - builds successfully, as expected
- `docfx serve` - indicates it is serving on port `8080`, as expected
- Follow the link from the terminal, which opens the port `8080` in a forwarded tab

### Expected Behavior

See the site at the root site at the `/_site` subdirectory which is where docfx serves items

### Actual Behavior

See a 502 bad gateway error at the initial URL, and also when attempting with `/_site` appended.

### Other Things I've tried

- I've pulled this branch in VS Code on my machine and opened it in this container. I was able to see the site served as expected on both the forwarded `8080` port root and with `/_site` appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Thanks to this comment: https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/3615#issuecomment-451664865

In this case, because docfx is using `WebApp.Start()`, the correct syntax inside of the container is:

`docfx serve _site -n "*"`

That `"*"` is what makes the difference here and allows mono to bind appropriately for the forwarding to work.